# How to implement SportLight search?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9

I am working with spotlight search, I have implemented all the required thinks in my functions but still not getting item in search, please suggest me.

```
-(void)functionForSportlightsearch{
    NSUserActivity *activity = [[NSUserActivity alloc] initWithActivityType:sportlightSearchID];
    activity.title = @"Item test";
    activity.keywords = [NSSet setWithArray:self.arrUnits];
    activity.eligibleForSearch = YES;
    [activity becomeCurrent]; 
  }
```

What think still missing to enable this, I was calling this in **viewDidLoad(RootviewController)**.

Comment: please show us how you handle this search activity ?

Answer (score 0):

With iOS 9, Apple upgrades Handoff, associating it with Spotlight.

For this, the application simply needs to register the launched activities (with NSUserActivity), as well as the content it presents (with Core Spotlight); then the system handles that information, indexing it either locally or on Apple servers.

> Apple stipulates that keywords should not be overused, with the
>   following warning for developers: irrelevant keywords will be detected
>   and the activity will not be searchable through them.

To handle a search result , a specific method in the appDelegate has to be implemented:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void(^)(NSArray *restorableObjects))restorationHandler
```

This method should recreate the view associated to the activity and present it to the user.

For more info : http://applidium.com/en/news/ios9_search_api/

Comment: We have to do something with info.plist file ?

Answer (score 0):

Also add the following line to the above code..

self.userActivity = activity;

**userActivity** is the UIResponder class property.